# NVidia NSight "process creation failure"

Tags: c++, opengl, archlinux, nsight

When launching my game from NVidia NSight, I get the following error message:

> Preparing to launch...
>
> Launch failure: Process creation failure
>
> Launch failed.

The game launches just fine, but with no way to attach to it, I can't do frame debugging or anything else. There is no other error message or information that is logged. This is on Arch Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably not the answer you were hoping for, but after running into the same problem, I sent a bug report to Nvidia (https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/bugs/nsight-graphics-bug-reporting) and I was told that Arch isn't supported at the moment (see https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-graphics-requirements).

It's possible that, if there is enough demand, support could be added. So feel free to send them some feedback/request as well.

As an alternative, for debugging, RenderDoc works well enough on Arch, but it's not very good for profiling.

Comment: The provided link shows `Developer Program Membership Required`. So it is useless. Therefore will be better to include the essential parts of the answer here.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, Arch Linux has now been officially supported by Nsight Graphics.

> Ubuntu 18.04, 20.04
>
> RHEL 7.6
>
> Centos 7.6
>
> **Arch Linux 2021.05.01**

https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-graphics-requirements

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29809441)